# How to access a list outside a class?

Tags: python

So I generated a bunch of places with the Place class, then in the Player class I tried to make a method that looks at the current location and look at the connected locations through the places list I made to travel west, however since I am very new the OOP I am not sure how to give access to the Player function to the list made in main()

```
def main():
    import random

    places = []
    places.append(Place("Boston", "Sunny - 55°F", ("Worcester", None), "645,966", "Marty Walsh"))
    places.append(Place("Worcester", "Sunny - 64°F", ("Springfield", "Boston"), "182,544", "Joseph Petty"))
    places.append(Place("Springfield", "Sunny - 67°F", ("Pittsfield", "Worcester"), "153,703", "Domenic Sarno"))
    places.append(Place("Pittsfield", "Sunny - 63°F", (None, "Springfield"), "44,057", "Linda Tyer"))
```

This is where the player is generated in main() as well:

```
player = Player(name, random.choice(places))
```

Here is the Place class constructor:

```
class Place(object):
    def __init__(self, name, weather, cl, pop, mayor):
        self.name = name
        self.weather = weather
        self.connectedLocation = cl
        self.population = pop
        self.mayor = mayor
```

Here is the Player class constructor:

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, name, curLoc):
        self.name = name
        self.curLoc = curLoc
```

Later in the Player class I attempted to make this method to no avail, since to my dismay the class cannot access the list of places made in main()

```
def goWest(self):
    for place in places:
        if self.curLoc.connectedLocation[0] == place.name:
            self.curLoc = place
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the places list to the `goWest` function by adding a places parameter to it.  It would look something like this:

```
def go_west(self, places):
    for place in places:
        if self.cur_loc.connected_location[0] == place.name:
            self.cur_loc = place
            break
```

I added the break statement because I am assuming that once you find the current location you don't need to keep iterating of the list.

Comment: Holy shit! I had no idea the solution would be so elegant, OOP ftw! I didn't know methods work just like functions do. Great to know! Thank you so much!

Comment: Yup, OOP is pretty great.  One other little OOP tip, instead of creating a places array in your main method try adding it as a class level attribute.  You can then put `self.places.append(self)` as the last line in the `Place` `__init__` method so the array just gets populated through the power of OOP ;).

Comment: Amazing! I just implemented it. It's so cool that you can create a list in the Places class right before the __init__ and it never makes it blank again.